# Specification for RJ-14 connectors and 4-wire flat cable?

Tags: cables

RJ-14 jack and plug should have some kind of standard to make sure that the parts from different manufacturers fit together, but I have not been able to find such information.

Can someone help to find that spec/drawing?

Same thing for 4-wire flat cable used with RJ-14. Where could I find the spec/drawing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RJ-14 **is** the standard which defines how a 6p4c modular jack connector should be wired.

What you seek are the drawings for a 6p4c modular jack.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Looks like the information is in this FCC doc: http://www.tscm.com/FCC47CFRpart68.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this Wikipedia page
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RJ14.svg

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cad model of the RJ-14 connector if that helps!
https://grabcad.com/library/tag/rj14